# Bug with finding closest frame to cursor

Tags: lua, roblox

So I have this script that I use to drag items into slots for crafting and I find what frame is closest to there cursor but for some reason it is not perfectly accurate, it has an offset down and to the right a little bit, here is the script and some pictures.

```
local UIS = game:GetService('UserInputService')

local frame = script.Parent

local mainFrame = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent

local dragToggle = nil

local dragSpeed = 0.25

local dragStart = nil

local startPos = nil


local function updateInput(input)

    local delta = input.Position - dragStart

    local position = UDim2.new(startPos.X.Scale, startPos.X.Offset + delta.X,

        startPos.Y.Scale, startPos.Y.Offset + delta.Y)

    currentTween = game:GetService('TweenService'):Create(frameToDrag, TweenInfo.new(dragSpeed), {Position = position})
    currentTween:Play()

end



frame.InputBegan:Connect(function(input)

    if (input.UserInputType == Enum.UserInputType.MouseButton1 or input.UserInputType == Enum.UserInputType.Touch) then 
        local pcall = function(succes, errorMessage)
            if not string.find(frameToDrag.Parent.Name, "Slot") then
                frameToDrag:Destroy()   
                end
        end
        frameToDrag = frame:Clone()
        frameToDrag.Parent = mainFrame
        frameToDrag.Stats:Destroy()
        frameToDrag.Size = UDim2.new(0.06, 0 ,0.15 , 0)
        dragToggle = true

        dragStart = input.Position
        startPos = frame.Position

        input.Changed:Connect(function()
        
            if input.UserInputState == Enum.UserInputState.End  and dragToggle then
                if (input.UserInputType ~= Enum.UserInputType.MouseButton1 or input.UserInputType ~= Enum.UserInputType.Touch) then
                currentTween:Pause()
                    dragToggle = false
                    local objects = {}
                    for _, v in pairs(mainFrame.CraftSlots:GetChildren()) do
                        if not v:IsA("UIGridLayout") and not v:IsA("LocalScript") and not v:IsA("ModuleScript")then -- Filtering out all of the non interface objects
                            table.insert(objects,v) 
                            end
                        
                    end
                    
                    local mouse = game:GetService('Players').LocalPlayer:GetMouse()
                    mainFrame.Parent.Dot.Position = UDim2.new(0, mouse.X, 0, mouse.Y)
                    local target = getClosestGui(-- List of gui objects
                    )-- Boom we got our target
                    if target:FindFirstChild("Template") then
                        target:FindFirstChild("Template"):Destroy()
                    end
                        frameToDrag.Parent = target
                        frameToDrag.Position = UDim2.new(0, 0 ,0 , 0)
                        frameToDrag.Size = UDim2.new(1, 0 , 1, 0) 
                        frameToDrag = nil
                    
                
                end
            end

        end)

    end

end)



UIS.InputChanged:Connect(function(input)

    if input.UserInputType == Enum.UserInputType.MouseMovement or input.UserInputType == Enum.UserInputType.Touch then

        if dragToggle then

            updateInput(input)

        end

    end

end)




function getClosestGui()
    local distanceArray = {}
    local mouse = game:GetService('Players').LocalPlayer:GetMouse()
    local posTable = {}
    for i, v in pairs(mainFrame.CraftSlots:GetChildren()) do
        if v:IsA("Frame") then
            table.insert(posTable, v)
        end
    end
    for i, v in pairs(posTable) do   --- difference is here below vvvvvvvvvv
    table.insert(distanceArray, i, math.sqrt(math.pow(mouse.X - v.AbsolutePosition.X, 2) + math.pow(mouse.Y - v.AbsolutePosition.Y, 2)))
        print(v.Name.. " - ".. math.sqrt(math.pow(mouse.X - v.AbsolutePosition.X, 2) + math.pow(mouse.Y - v.AbsolutePosition.Y, 2)))
end

local min = math.min(table.unpack(distanceArray))
local nearest = posTable[table.find(distanceArray, min)] 



return nearest
end
```

[crafting grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOeuP.jpg)

So I have tried using other methods of doing this but all of them have failed, I tried setting a green dot to the cursor position and it worked perfectly fine help is much appreciated.